# What's the best way to display Exception in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I'm a newbie in Flask and I am trying to display the [Built-In Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html) in python but I can't seem to have them display on my end.

NOTE:

```
set FLASK_DEBUG = 0
```

CODE:

```
def do_something:
    try:
        doing_something()
    except Exception as err:
        return f"{err}"
```

Expectation:

- It will display one of the built-in exceptions:

  - KeyError
  - IndexError
  - NameError
  - Etc.

Reality:

- It will return the line of code that didn't worked which is more ambiguous to the end user.

Also:

- I have no problem seeing the errors when the debug mode is ON but that's not something that I want to do if I open them in public

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Flask` supplies you with a function that enables you to register an error handler throughout your entire `app`; you can do something as shown below:

```
def handle_exceptions(e):
    # Log exception in your logs
    # get traceback and sys exception info and log as required   
    # app.logger.error(getattr(e, 'description', str(e)))

    # Print traceback

    # return your response using getattr(e, 'code', 500) etc. 

# Exception is used to catch all exceptions
app.register_error_handler(Exception, handle_exceptions)
```

In my honest opinion, this is the way to go. - Following the structure found in `werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException` as an example is a solid foundation.

Having a unified exception handler that will standardise your `Exception` handling, visualisation and logging will make your life a tad better. :)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to read about app.logger.error as I usually import logger instead of this way of coding :)

Comment: I personally, store the `handle_exceptions` out of the `app.py` initialisation file. - Cleaner. - If you're using a custom log handler (which I hope you are, if not; http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/logging/#email-errors-to-admins can act as example of how to create your own log handler - for rotation, formatting, alerts et cetera.), then you'd need to either use `current_app` to do something like `current_app.logger.error()` or `app.logger.error()` - the log handler will be registered using the `addHandler` function and therefore you'd need to use the `app`.

Answer (score 3):

Try with this:

```
def do_something:
    try:
        doing_something()
    except Exception as err:
        return f"{err.__class__.__name__}: {err}"
```

Comment: Thanks! this is actually what I'm looking for :)